# GPS generate street

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, bigdata, data-science-model

I am working on GPS tracking with a huge data from vehicle.

Dataset have: vehicleId, speed, orientation(0-360), **coordinate** (x,y) and **timestamp**.

Can you recommend me how to clean data and model to generate street(route) from data?

[image: GPS on Map] just 1000 GPS. I have about 500k GPS

Thank you so much

Comment: Is gps data available in each moment? Or it assumes that there are some whitespaces in vehicle location at some moments, that should be predicted by the model to reconstruct street map?

Comment: Yes. There are many noise in dataset. One of reason is GPS that is inaccuracy when tracking.

Comment: Many point are in an area, that may be a rush hour or a place parking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use ml or dl (as you've choose such tags to the question), you should clarify what is the final target. Is it correct streets representation? But if it's so, I guess it would be enough to develop algorithm without ml implementation, which will use input data to calculate length and angle of each street. Basically the timestamp of gps data isn't big (less than half minute, if I understand correct, based on this article https://towardsdatascience.com/how-tracking-apps-analyse-your-gps-data-a-hands-on-tutorial-in-python-756d4db6715d), I think it will be enough for the algorithm. If you have some specific noise or whitespaces in data, then it's reasonable to add ml. According to the street topic, it's usual can be represented as graph and maybe the problem can be considered as passing through the graph (but it's just a hint for thinking) in order to optimize high amount of data (not to include the same route twice)

Comment: I have update my questions. Thank you hint. That also a good way to generate route on map.

Comment: Also, in data I had, there are many noise and whitespaces so I think ML and DL is good choice to predict route (street) on map.
Cleaning data is also complex problem and I don't know how to start.